# in 'C' How do I - Check user input for int and if letters, characters or spaces it reprompts the user?

Tags: c, null, user-input, scanf, boolean-expression

it has to be a non-negative int no larger than 23....no blank entries or other entries, if so it reprompts the user again 
I have

```
int main(void){
int rows;


while (rows < 1 || rows > 23)
{
printf("Height:");
scanf("%d", &rows);
}
```

then idk what to do for the other.

is it NULL? orrrr what lol
how would I implement that

Comment: Undefined behavior. `rows` is uninitialized and might contain 18 if unlucky.

Comment: Note that 0 is a non-negative integer; your code, though, rejects it as invalid.  If you mean 'positive integer', use that term.  If you mean 0 is valid, fix the comparison.  As it is, the problem specification is ambiguous between the code and the verbiage.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by initializing `rows` (its *undefined* initial garbage value could be 18 if you are unlucky)....

Read an entire line using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or else [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html).

Then parse that line using [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (take into account the result of `sscanf` and perhaps use `%n`) or using [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) (e.g. `long n=strtol(p,0,&end);` after declaring `char *end=NULL;`)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20843838/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171511/841108) answers.

Or at least, use the result of `scanf` like

```
int rows = 0;
while(1) {
 puts("number of rows?");
 fflush(stdout);
 int nbscan = scanf("%d", &rows);
 if (nbscan<=0) continue;
 if (rows < 1 || rows>20) continue;
 if (feof(stdin)) break;
}
```